# XSL : How to pass variable to for each

Tags: xslt-1.0

```
<xsl:for-each select="$script/startWith">
  <xsl:variable name = "i" > 
    <xsl:value-of select="$script/startWith[position()]"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:for-each select="JeuxDeMots/Element">
    <xsl:variable name = "A" > 
      <xsl:value-of select="eName"/>
    </xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:if test="starts-with($A,$i)= true()">
      <xsl:variable name="stringReplace">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($i,0,3)"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="$stringReplace"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>   
</xsl:for-each>
```

Problem :  variable $i, can not pass in an xsl for-each.
Please help me.

Comment: I do this all the time. Try removing the spaces around the equals sign in the variable declaration: <xsl:variable name="i" >

Comment: Thanks,but not working .

Comment: What is the error message, you're getting? On which line (there are two references to *i*)?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the declaration of `i` with

```
<xsl:variable name="i" select="string(.)"/>
```

The context item (i.e. ".") is different for each evaluation of the for-each instruction, but the value of the expression `$script/startWith[position()]` does not change.  (Here, you are making a sequence of `startWith` elements, and testing each one for the effective boolean value of the expression `position()`.  The expression `position()` returns a positive integer, so its effective boolean value is always true.  So the predicate `[position()]` is doing no work at all here.

Also, you'll want to replace the declaration of `stringReplace` with

```
<xsl:variable name="stringReplace" select="substring($i,1,3)"/>
```

(String offsets begin with 1 in XPath, not with 0.)

I am guessing that you want to process all of the `startWith` children of `$script`, and for each one emit the first three characters of the `startWith` value once, for each startWith/JeuxDeMots/Element whose `eName` child begins with the value of startWith.

Actually, the whole thing might be a little easier to read if it were briefer and more direct:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$script/startWith">
  <xsl:variable name = "i" select="string()"/> 
  <xsl:for-each select="JeuxDeMots/Element">
    <xsl:if test="starts-with(eName,$i)">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($i,1,3)"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>   
</xsl:for-each>
```

It makes perfect sense to create the variables $A and $stringReplace if they are used several times in code you're not showing us, but if not, ...

Comment: Correct.  If you set the context node to a startWith element in script.xml and then write relative XPath expressions like JeuxDeMots/Element or root/book, those relative XPath expressions are not going to match anything in the primary input document.  Pay attention to the context node; you'll never understand XPath until you do.  And you'll never be able to use XSLT effectively until you understand XPath.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you change context in first for-each. Then the element JeuxDeMots is not "visible" for second for-each. You can for example try to store it in variable and use this variable in second for-each (there are also another ways how to figure out this problem).

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="doc" select="JeuxDeMots"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$script/startWith">
            <xsl:for-each select="$script/startWith">
                <xsl:variable name="i">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:for-each select="$doc/Element">
                    <xsl:variable name="A">
                        <xsl:value-of select="eName"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:if test="starts-with($A,$i) = true()">
                        <xsl:variable name="stringReplace">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring($i,0,3)"/>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$stringReplace"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Although I'm not sure what exactly you are dealing with it seems to output desired value AsAt.

You could also consider C.M.Sperberg-McQueen post about string offset in XPath.